# Is there a way to refresh the Excel with PowerQuery data programmatically, and then save it, e.g. as a csv file?

Tags: excel, powerquery

The scenario is: I have A.csv and B.csv, then I use power query to combine the data in the 2 csv files in C.xls.

The result I want to achieve is: I have an external tool so that after I modify any of the csv files, I just need to run the tool, instead of to open C.xls, the content of C.xls will be updated automatically. Of course, if it could be saved to C.csv, it will be perfect.